# Authorization and charging flow with Shopify

Tags: asp.net, workflow, shopify

I am developing an addon for Shopify platform and using the [Shopify NET library](https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/shopify.net) I have managed to authorize the user shop and gather some data.

Now I need to charge the usage of the Addon with a monthly fee (providing 7 days trial) but I cannot figure out the flow I must follow.

I guess that I have to call [Recurring Application Charge API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/recurringapplicationcharge) after the user authenticates (at the callback from the authorization URL) and if the user declines the charge then I have to log him out. Is that correct?

Do I have to care for providing 7 days trial by myself or the Shopify [RACharge API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/recurringapplicationcharge) with manage it by itself?

What do I have to do when the user cancel the subscription or freeze it?

Can anyone point me out a document that analyze the charging flow except the [Shopify Billing API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/shopify-billing-api) which is not that helpful after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question, you're right. You either have to log out the user or you just let him authed without permission to see some views or all of them.
There's a propperty on Recurring Application which allows you to define the days of the trial: "Number of days that the customer is eligible for a free trial.", so Shopify handles this for you.

When user cancels a subscription or his store is put on "frozen" status, you should make sure he doesn't have access to your App functionalities, though if it's frozen, he won't even be able to log into his store.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. I am getting the last charge and check if it is accepted. Do you think that it is enough?

Comment: I'd need to deep a bit more on your flow in order to tell you if you're going with the right approach.

Comment: @Alexander, I have 20 days of trial in my app. After creating the charge, immediately need to send confirmation url to customer so that he can accept and decline the charge? Also if he declined the charge then can he still use the trial?

Comment: @TBI you don't need to tell the user of your Shopify app whether he wants to accept or decline the charge, this is done by Shopify. If he declines the charge, he won't be able to use your app. Shopify blocks the view, before requesting your app to show any data.